# why std::move works with constant object

Tags: c++

Why the following code is legal. As per my understanding test's constructor parameter s1 is referring to constant object and after the calling std::move(), object's state should be changed So it should give error but its working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<memory>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class test
{
   string s;
public:
  test( const string& s1) : s(std::move(s1))
  {

  }
};
int main()
{
  test t1("data");
}
```

Comment: `std::move` does not move anything, it's just a cast.

Comment: `s` is initialised with `const std::string&&`. Given the fact, that `std::string` does not have constructor that matches this signature, it is initialised via copy c-tor, since it is the only one that suits. So - even though you call `std::move`, you end up making a copy and initialising `s` via the copy c-tor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `std::move` makes moving an object *possible*. It does not actually move anything. That would be the move constructor of `s`.

But since the result of the move here will still be `const` it won't call the move constructor. It will call the copy constructor.

Try it. You'll see.